# Logstash: How to extract an object without knowing keyname

Tags: json, ruby, logstash

The input JSON I am expecting contains a fields that contains some objects. The key of the object is expected to be random so I cannot specify that in the logstash yml file.

Sample JSON:

```json
{
    "RootKey": {
        "FieldName": {
            "SubField": "SubFieldValue"
        }
    }
}
```

The "FieldName" itself could be any random string in the input, so the same JSON might look like this in a diferent event -

```json
{
    "RootKey": {
        "SomeDifferentFieldName": {
            "SubField": "SubFieldValue"
        }
    }
}
```

Weirdly enough, the "SubField" key name is going to be static.

I thought I could do something like this -

`mutate { add_field => { fieldValue=> "[RootKey][0][SubField]" } }`

But that seems to work fine for arrays and not an object.
Any other representations run into error -
eg.

`mutate { add_field => { fieldValue => "[RootKey][][SubField]" } }`

`mutate { add_field => { fieldValue=> "[RootKey]{0}[SubField]" } }`

`mutate { add_field => { fieldValue=> "[RootKey]{}[SubField]" } }`

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a ruby filter. Try

```
ruby {
    code => '
        root = event.get("RootKey")
        if root
            root.each { |x|
                event.set("fieldValue", x["SubField"])
            }
        end
    '
}
```